# Spring Cloud Config Composite Repositories

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I was trying to configure the spring cloud config server to use a composite configuration but i got a weird error.
What am I doing wrong?

**1. Native profile**

> application.properties

```
server.port=8888    
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///C:/tmp/config-repo
```

http://localhost:8888/app1/dev/ -> got the loaded properties

**2. Composite profile (Native + custom)**

> application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=composite
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///C:/tmp/config-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.plugins.search-locations=file:///C:/tmp/plugins-repo
```

**Error:**
*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$271d7a4d]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository*

The PluginsEnvironmentRepository returns an Environment filled up with all the properties found in each property file existing in the configured folder.
This class is just a sample so I din't implement any filter on the application/profile/label parameters.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config.server.plugins")
public class PluginsEnvironmentRepository implements EnvironmentRepository, Ordered {
    private int order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    private String searchLocations;

    @Override
    public Environment findOne(String application, String profile, String label) {

        String[] profiles = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(profile);
        Environment env = new Environment(application, profiles, label, null, null);

        String[] locations = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(searchLocations);
        for (String location : locations) {
            File f = new File(URI.create(location));
            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                File[] propFiles = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                        return pathname.getName().endsWith(".properties");
                    }
                });

                for (File propFile : propFiles) {
                    env.add(new PropertySource(propFile.getName(), loadProperties(propFile)));
                }
            }
        }

        return env;
    }

    private Map<String, String> loadProperties(File f) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public String getSearchLocations() {
        return searchLocations;
    }

    public void setSearchLocations(String searchLocations) {
        this.searchLocations = searchLocations;
    }

}
```

> Spring Cloud version : Edgware.SR2
>
> Spring Boot version : 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Looks like behavior of composite profiles was improved in spring cloud config release 2.0.0 (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/616) which is part of Finchley.RELEASE (and should be used with spring boot 2.0.3). - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Finchley-Release-Notes

But I was NOT able to launch your example and have composite profile of native+custom repos. It works fine if I change it to other composite combinations (git+custom or native+git). Maybe there is a bug or didn't manage to configure it.

Comment: @nymk Please can you share sample config for git+custom or native+git . though i'm trying to achieve native+custom. Thanks

Comment: @user3177744 are you able to resolve this yet, kindly share your solution

Comment: I have resolved to using local git (i.e with 'basedir') with custom repo environment